# .NET Core 6 - How to set ILogger(log4net) for Dependency Injection in Program.cs

Tags: asp.net-core, log4net

I've moved my new projects to **.NET Core 6** but apparently there are radical changes in Program and Startup.cs files.

I would like to use log4net in every Controller with Dependency Injection but I couldn't find any tutorial about Logging in **.NET Core 6.**

What I tried:

```
builder.Services.AddLogging();
builder.Logging.AddProvider(loggerProvider);
```

What should I write to use ILogger in Controllers?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The Logging in ASP.NET Core 6.0 is described in detail in the [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-6.0). A very brief summary: You register the logging framework you want to use and then use ASP.NET Core's log layer in the application itself. The translation between the two log systems is done by a handler. For log4net there is a handler on [GitHub](https://github.com/huorswords/Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Log4Net.AspNetCore).

### Registration

After you have installed the handler package, you register this handler in the initialization code in Program.cs:

```cs
// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();

// Add your logging handler
builder.Logging.AddLog4Net();

var app = builder.Build();
```

If you have an old-style template with a separate `Startup.cs`, you must use the sample code from the project's readme file instead.

### Write logs

Now you can get an instance of `ILogger` in your controllers via the Dependency Injection and log with it. The handler takes care of passing these logs to log4net accordingly.

```cs
private readonly ILogger<HomeController> logger;

public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger)
{
    this.logger = logger;
}

public IActionResult Index()
{
    this.logger.LogDebug("Creating /Home/Index");
    return View();
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Jann. I have couldn't found  it. Thank you again!

Comment: And how do you use GetCurrentMethod or GetCurrentClass?

Comment: Not on same topic but... You can get both the executing method and class name by using System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name and 
System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType.FullName

Answer (score 2):

When I use log4net in .Net6, the NLog has always been invoked.
I find `builder.Logging.AddLog4Net()` is necessary.

```cs
    builder.Logging.ClearProviders();
    builder.Logging.AddLog4Net();
```