# ILoggerProvider with generic types

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, onion-architecture

colleagues!

Im trying to create app with Onion arch and several GUI. I used lib Log4net as my log provider. I created my own IMyLoger interface at application layer, then implement this interface at infrastructure layer, and created an IMyLoger to ILogger adapter. But I recieved a trouble when I tried to implement ILogProvider intrface. Trouble is consist that ILog provider doesnt contain "Create"-methods with generic ILogger.

I think, that it is possible in the ASP.NET Core, becuse ILogger is used at default Controllers template.

So, how can I add ILogger at ILoggerProvider's method Create?

This is my AppLayer interface:

```
public interface IVbLogger<TState> where TState : class
{
    void Debug(string message);
    void Debug(string message, Exception ex);
    public void Warn(string message);
    void Warn(string message, Exception ex);
    void Info(string message);
    void Info(string message, Exception ex);
    void Error(string message);
    void Error(string message, Exception ex);
    void Fatal(string message);
    void Fatal(string message, Exception ex);



}
```

Log Adapders code:

```
public class Log4NetAdapter : ILogger<Log4NetAdapter> 
{
    readonly IVbLogger<Log4NetAdapter> _logger;
    
    public Log4NetAdapter()
    {
        _logger = new VbLogger<Log4NetAdapter>();
    }

    public IDisposable BeginScope<TState>(TState state)
    {
        return null;
    }

    public bool IsEnabled(LogLevel logLevel)
    {
        return _logger != null;
    }
   
    public void Log<TState>(LogLevel logLevel, EventId eventId, TState state, Exception? exception, Func<TState, Exception?, string> formatter)
    {
        Action<string, Exception> act;
        switch (logLevel)
        {
            case LogLevel.Debug:
                act = _logger.Debug;
                break;
            case LogLevel.Information:
                act = _logger.Info;
                break;
            case LogLevel.Trace:
                act = _logger.Debug;
                break;
            case LogLevel.Warning:
                act = _logger.Warn;
                break;
            case LogLevel.Error:
                act = _logger.Error;
                break;
            case LogLevel.Critical:
                act = _logger.Fatal;
                break;
            default:
                return;
        }

        act.Invoke(formatter(state, exception), exception);  
    }
}
```

And finally ILoggerProvider:

```
public class Log4NetProvider : ILoggerProvider
{
    public ILogger CreateLogger(string categoryName)
    {
        return new Log4NetAdapter();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are facing issues while writing the logs.

To write the logs, you could refer to the code example below.

```
private readonly ILogger<HomeController> logger;

public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger)
{
    this.logger = logger;
}

public IActionResult Index()
{
    this.logger.LogDebug("Creating /Home/Index");
    return View();
}
```

For more information, you could see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71131332/10309381)

Below are some helpful documents.

1. [How to use Log4Net with ASP.NET Core for logging](https://dotnetthoughts.net/how-to-use-log4net-with-aspnetcore-for-logging/)
2. [Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Log4Net.AspNetCore](https://github.com/huorswords/Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Log4Net.AspNetCore)

Comment: I know, that default controllers constructors take generic ILogger... But how can I add ILogger<T> at ILoggerProvider's method Create?

Comment: ASP.NET MVC is just a Presentation, in my case. So I cant to add Nuget packages in the ASP.NET project.

Comment: do you mean you can't add NuGet package for Log4net but you would like to use it in the Asp.Net Core project?